# What are possible consequences for applications that depends on Safe Mode for security?

Tags: appsec, php, secure-coding

PHP finally removed safe_mode feature:

[Safe Mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php)

> Warning
>
> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP
> 5.4.0.
>
> The PHP safe mode is an attempt to solve the shared-server security
> problem. It is architecturally incorrect to try to solve this problem
> at the PHP level, but since the alternatives at the web server and OS
> levels aren't very realistic, many people, especially ISP's, use safe
> mode for now.

My question is:

**What are possible consequences for applications that depends on Safe Mode for security?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason why safe mode should be removed is because its doesn't work.  Over the years people have found many ways of [bypassing PHP's safe mode](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?query=safe%20mode%20bypass&search_type=all&cves=on).

But the lack of enforceability is only one reason reason why Zend chose to remove "safe mode".  This is a quote taken from the [PHP 6 minutes discussion](http://www.php.net/~derick/meeting-notes.html#safe-mode):

> As safe_mode is a name that gives the wrong signals as making PHP
>   safe, we all agreed that we should remove this function. It can never
>   be made totally safe as there will always be ways to circumvent
>   safe_mode through libraries. This kind of functionality also better
>   belongs in the web server or other security scheme. open_basedir is a
>   feature that we will keep, and we will point users to this
>   functionality in the error message that is thrown when we detect this
>   setting on start-up.

Comment: + for the reason that why safe mode disabled, however, Zend should provide some points for risk assessment when upgrading PHP (from safe mode to disabled safe mode).